# How to count the total number of items in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Below is my code I am using to retrieve the data from my repeater table.
This gives the output in multi dimensional array. Please check the output too.

I want to get the total number of items in the whole multidimensional array and total number of items in each array.

In more detail, the whole multidimensional array has 30 items and 6 items in each array I want to get those two values.
How to count those two values?

```
var RepeaterTable = element.all(by.repeater("view in ctrl.view track by $index")).each(function(rowelem,index){
                     rowelem.getText().then(function(BlockTrans){
                         console.log("****index and RowElem\n"+index+"\n",BlockTrans);
                         var item = BlockTrans;
                     });


                 });
```

### output for the above code

```
0
Morrison
Male
Jun 22, 2017
26
Yes
Edit
****index and RowElem
1
Steven
Male
Jun 22, 2017
39
Yes
Edit
****index and RowElem
2
Emy
Female
Jun 22, 2017
27
Yes
Edit
****index and RowElem
3
Emily
Female
Jun 22, 2017
18
Yes
Edit
****index and RowElem
4
Michael
Male
Jun 22, 2017
46
Yes
Edit
```

Comment: There are 31 values, not 2. You will have 30 rows numbers and 1 total number.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively go through each element, count all elements if it's an array and return the amount

**example**

```
function getTotalElementCount (obj) {
    /* This number will contain the total amount of elements in the given variable obj.
     * This means all subelements will also be counted there.
     */
    let count = 0; 
    // If obj is an array, we want to find out how many elements and subelements it contains
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        // We call this function for every element (elem) in obj to get the total amount of elements in elem
        obj.foreach ((elem) => {
            // We increment the count by all elements in elem
            count += getTotalElementCount(elem);
        }
    } else {
         /* Element is not an array, so we can't go deeper. 
          * This means this obj is only a single element
          */
        return 1;
        /* you can also do this.
         * count = 1;
         */
    }
    return count;
}
```

Please tell me if my example was not clear enough

Comment: How you counting both values ?..The total number in the whole array and total number in each single array. The code is not that clear to understand.

Comment: Why would you return 1 if `obj` is not an array?

Comment: More help will be appreciated.

Comment: I added some comments. Please tell me if something else is off

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried **count** method in Protractor.

**For example:**

```
countElement(locator: string) {
    return element.all(by.css(locator)).count();
}
```